# display ajax content only after everything loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, loader

In my new website, there are number of ajax calls.Now the content is displaying when it's ready. I want to add a pre-loader until everything in the div gets loaded completely.
I've used **load()** function  but its not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jQuery [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event:

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received.